# Deselecting a chart in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In reference to the following *file.xlsm*:

[image: first image]

where *Sheet1* (1) is a Sheet, *Plot1* (2) is a Graphic-Sheet and the button (3) refers to the following Macro:

```
Sub plot()

ReDim blue(1 To 5, 1 To 2)
ReDim red(1 To 5, 1 To 2)
For i = 1 To 5
    blue(i, 1) = i
    blue(i, 2) = i ^ 2
    red(i, 1) = i + 4
    red(i, 2) = (i + 4) ^ 2
Next i

Sheets("Plot1").Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.ClearContents
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Application.Index(blue, , 1)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Application.Index(blue, , 2)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Application.Index(red, , 1)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Application.Index(red, , 2)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
Selection.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Sheets("Plot1").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=False
Sheets("Plot1").Unprotect
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

- after opening *file.xlsm*, clicking (3) and (2) I get:

[image: second image]

- after opening *file.xlsm*, clicking (2), (1), (3) and (2) I get:

[image: third image]

> How can I change the Macro so that I always get the third image regardless of the click sequence?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible to deselect a chart, that is, an embedded chart, but I don't remember if it worked on a chart sheet.

For some reason, no matter what I try, the chart area becomes selected when this code is first run after opening the workbook. (I even tried activating the chart sheet, then the worksheet, with a Workbook_Open procedure: no luck.) But you can avoid having the second series selected if you don't select it in the first place. Not selecting things actually makes the code run faster, usually not enough that you would notice, but it also prevents the little flash of tabs being activated.

```
Sub plot()

    ReDim blue(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Double
    ReDim red(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        blue(i, 1) = i
        blue(i, 2) = i ^ 2
        red(i, 1) = i + 4
        red(i, 2) = (i + 4) ^ 2
    Next i

    With Charts("Plot1")

        .ChartArea.ClearContents
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = Application.Index(blue, , 1)
            .Values = Application.Index(blue, , 2)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End With

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = Application.Index(red, , 1)
            .Values = Application.Index(red, , 2)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```